# A proof of showing some flow is global

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Given a flow $\Phi_i(t,p)$ defined on $A_i=\mathbb{R}\times E$, and $f$ is a proper map from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $f\Phi_i(t,p)=f(q)+e_it$. And define $J_q$ by $A_i=\cup_{q\in E}J_q\times\{q\}$. Now the following proof shows $\Phi_i(t,p)$ is global.

[image]

The Lemma 7.3.6 is here:
[image]

My question is we don't know if $J_q$ is bounded, how can we apply what the author said about bounded open interval and the lemma 7.3.6 to give the contradiction?

Comment: I think it's poorly worded.  The author is assuming $J_q$ is bounded to arrive at the contradiction.  That is, suppose $\Phi_i$ is not global, then for some $q\in E$, the interval $J_q$ is a bounded open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.  The proof then shows a contradiction and hence that $J_q=\mathbb{R}$, and hence $A_i=\mathbb{R}\times E$.

Comment: @Matt thanks, but if a flow is not global, does it have to have some slice $J_q$ to be bounded?

Comment: By definition:  A smooth flow $\theta$ is a smooth map $\theta:\mathcal{D}\to E$ where $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times E$ is a domain such that for each $p\in E$, the set $\mathcal{D}_p=\{t\in\mathbb{R}:(t,p)\in\mathcal{D}\}$ is an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$.  If $\theta$ is global, then $\mathcal{D}=\mathbb{R}\times E$, and in particular, for each $p\in E$, you have that $\mathcal{D}_p=R$ (since $(t,p)\in\mathcal{D}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  If $\theta$ is not global, then there exists $p\in E$ such that $\mathcal{D}_p\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$ and thus must be bounded.

Comment: @Matt But $D_p\not=\mathbb{R}$ doesn't imply $D_p$ is unbounded, for example, I think it's possible that $D_p$ can be $(-\infty,5)$

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion.  The lower bound isn't important for the Escape Lemma.  Cf. Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds:  If $\gamma:J\to M$ is a smooth maximal integral curve for a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$, where $J\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $b:=\sup{J}<\infty$, then for any $t_0\in J$, $\gamma([t_0,b))$ is not contained in any compact subset of $M$.

Comment: @Matt but $D_p$ can also be like $(-1,\infty)$ and why is that related to the existence of a bounded $D_p$?

Comment: The Escape Lemma works in both directions (just reverse time in the integral curve).  If $J\neq\mathbb{R}$, then at least one of $-\infty<\inf{J}$ or $\sup{J}<\infty$ must hold.  Without loss of generality, assume $J=(-\infty,b)$, $b<\infty$.  Fix $t_0<b$, let $J_0=[t_0,B)$.  The image of this set is not contained in any compact set.

Comment: @Matt, Thanks, that makes sense!